# Importing html file into excel - getting the color palette right

Tags: c#, html, excel, colors, import

I have an html file which contains a table, the table uses colours to indicate different types of data. I need to be able to import this into excel with the right color palette.

I am importing the html file using:

```
//using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

var excel = new Application(excel);
excel.Workbooks.OpenXML(fileName); //where filename is the path to the html file.
```

I am then using

```
_excel.Workbooks[1].Colors
```

to add the colors that are used in the html file.

This seems to change some of the colors of some of the elements in the spreadsheet but not the ones I expect. What order do I need to add them in? Can I extend the color palette in excel beyond 56? How are you supposed to use the color palette in excel when importing an html file?

Answer (score 0):

The color palette has 56 entries.  As far as I can tell, you can't change that.

Comment: Can a new color palette be created and the current one be overridden using an app. level plugin in Excel or Powerpoint?